# Calculate the order of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

The matrix is composed only of $+\frac{1}4$ and $-\frac14$, and it is an orthogonal matrix, which means $$A A^{T} = I$$

And I want to know the order of such matrix.

If I want get the identity matrix, there would be some equations of $A$'s elements, but the order is unknown, which is confusing.

Comment: Consider the first row of $A$ (containing only $\pm \frac{1}{4}$s). The $(1,1)$-entry of $AA^T$ is just the sum of the squares of the first row of $A$. What (and therefore how many) should these elements be if the sum of their squares is $1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = [a_{ij}]_{(n\times n)}$. Then $(AA^T)_{11} = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{1j}^2 = (I)_{11} = 1$. Try to get the answer now. Or read further.

As each $a_{ij} = \pm \dfrac{1}{4}$, each $a_{1j}^2 = \dfrac{1}{16}$, so $\sum_{j=1}^n a_{1j}^2 = \dfrac{n}{16}$. Then what is $n$ (considering our first observation)?

$\dfrac{n}{16} = 1$, so $n = 16$ is the order of $A$ (if such a matrix exists at all).

Now actually construct $A$ by figuring out the distibution of $+$s and $-$s (it might be easier to consider a matrix of $\pm 1$s and then replace the $1$s with $\frac{1}{4}$s to get $A$).

Comment: Thanks,  I neglect the most easy method. :)